# Can't access already created mail account in Sylpheed

Tags: lubuntu, gmail, sylpheed

I'm using GMail. I created an IMAP4-account using the wizard. It shows the folder with my account name but it doesn't open on a double-click and clicking on "get mail" doesn't do anything. I did a reboot, uinstalled Sylpheed and reinstalled. I used the "purge" command but after reinstalling, my account was there again. I still can't get my mail. The "delete account"-option you get when you right-click on it is greyed out by the way, so I can't delete and re-create it.

Comment: Sylpheed is fast and nice, but it is kind of outdated and is wonky in my opinion.  Thunderbird just came out with a new version and it is faster and cleaner.  If you use the threaded conversations extension it gets really nice.  Also there is a program called Geary that is a new email client that is much faster then Sylpheed.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You uninstalled the application but did not delete your user profile folder.

Where this is found depends on your operating system, for example:

- Linux ~/.sylpheed-2.0
- Windows 2000/XP: C:\Documents and Settings(user name)\Application Data\Sylpheed
- Windows Vista/Seven: C:\Users(user name)\AppData\Roaming\Sylpheed